# Weka NaiveBayes Classifier giving different (wrong?) means/standard-deviation on numerical values

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have tried to classify using both a NaiveBayes classifier and a NaiveBayesSimple classifier, using the following data:

```
@attribute a real
@attribute b {yes, no}                                                                                        

@data                                                                                                            
1,yes
3,yes
5,yes
2,yes
1,yes
4,no
7,no
5,no
8,no
9,no
```

When using the NaiveBayesSimple classifier, I get the mean and variance values I expect:

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Naive Bayes (simple)

Class yes: P(C) = 0.5       

Attribute a
Mean: 2.4           Standard Deviation: 1.67332005



Class no: P(C) = 0.5       

Attribute a
Mean: 6.6           Standard Deviation: 2.07364414
```

However, when using the NaiveBayes classifier, I get different values:

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Naive Bayes Classifier

            Class
Attribute         yes     no
                (0.5)  (0.5)
=============================
a
  mean          2.5143 6.6286
  std. dev.     1.3328 1.8286
  weight sum         5      5
  precision     1.1429 1.1429
```

I was wondering what the cause of the shifting mean/SD was? I've read through the paper that the NaiveBayes classifier is based on: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.8.3257 and can't see any reason for it there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The two algorithms differ from each other.

Naive bayes in Weka is defined as follows:

> NAME weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes
>
> SYNOPSIS Class for a Naive Bayes classifier using estimator classes.
>   Numeric estimator precision values are chosen based on analysis of the
>   training data. For this reason, the classifier is not an
>   UpdateableClassifier (which in typical usage are initialized with zero
>   training instances) -- if you need the UpdateableClassifier
>   functionality, use the NaiveBayesUpdateable classifier. The
>   NaiveBayesUpdateable classifier will  use a default precision of 0.1
>   for numeric attributes when buildClassifier is called with zero
>   training instances.
>
> For more information on Naive Bayes classifiers, see
>
> George H. John, Pat Langley: Estimating Continuous Distributions in
>   Bayesian Classifiers. In: Eleventh Conference on Uncertainty in
>   Artificial Intelligence, San Mateo, 338-345, 1995.
>
> OPTIONS debug -- If set to true, classifier may output additional info
>   to the console.
>
> displayModelInOldFormat -- Use old format for model output. The old
>   format is better when there are many class values. The new format is
>   better when there are fewer classes and many attributes.
>
> useKernelEstimator -- Use a kernel estimator for numeric attributes
>   rather than a normal distribution.
>
> useSupervisedDiscretization -- Use supervised discretization to
>   convert numeric attributes to nominal ones.

and NaiveBayesSimple is defined as follows:

> NAME weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesSimple
>
> SYNOPSIS Class for building and using a simple Naive Bayes
>   classifier.Numeric attributes are modelled by a normal distribution.
>
> For more information, see
>
> Richard Duda, Peter Hart (1973). Pattern Classification and Scene
>   Analysis. Wiley, New York.
>
> OPTIONS debug -- If set to true, classifier may output additional info
>   to the console.